# How to derive the graviton propagator in curved spacetime?

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, greens-functions, propagator, qft-in-curved-spacetime

Is it possible to derive the graviton propagator in curved spacetime from the graviton propagator in Minkowski spacetime?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is likely no.

The correct way to find the propagator is to linearize Einstein's equations in the curved background (which must be a solution). The linearized perturbation satisfies a second-order differential equation of the form $\mathring{D}_{\mu\nu}{}^{\rho\sigma} h_{\rho\sigma}(x) = 0$. The propagator is then obtained by solving the differential equation
$$
\mathring{D}_{\mu\nu}{}^{\rho\sigma} G_{\rho\sigma,\alpha\beta}(x,y) = \mathring{g}_{\mu\langle\alpha}(x) \mathring{g}_{\beta\rangle\nu}(x) \delta(x-y)
$$
where $\mathring{g}$ is the background geometry around which you are perturbing.

The reason I say "likely no" instead of just no is that it might be possible to think of the curved geometry as a coherent state of gravitons in the Minkowski background. In that case, the Minkowski propagator can be used to find the $G$, but I suspect that a calculation of this type will be quite difficult.

Comment: I know what parentheses and square brackets mean around indices. What do angle brackets mean?

Comment: $\langle ~\rangle$ denotes the symmetric traceless part of a tensor. Sometimes, people also use $\{~ \}$ for this.